# sustainsys.saml2 IdP initiated Logout

Tags: sustainsys-saml2

We are getting a funny error message using this library.  During an IdP initiated logout, we get a 404 error and the following HTML in SAML tracer:
any ideas?

GET https://testportal.myatphub.ca/AuthServices/Logout?SAMLRequest=rVbZsqJIEH33K27Yj0ZfdhDj9o1AQURBkUWFlw6WAlkLKZDl68fbtyd6i5no6ZjXU1knz0kyqXxBXpFXCxXGsG0McGsBap6e%2BiIv0eLL0adpW5cL6KEELUqvAGjRBAtT0NQF%2BYwvqho2MID59EkRP00RSQPABFE0J0IyDEOfDHyPCAMuIkLOpwDwGdL3SJykpk8nUKMElp%2BmD5rHbYRaoJSo8crmAeHE%2FCPOfyRpi2AXNL2g5%2B70SXxIS0qv%2BXLr2jQVWmBY8wArWDde%2FlwMXlNdW%2F858DChba4mqO9JABD2bm76tIfNoTzUQtSA%2BuckzHuS15c304svcurvyvDvVfAQAvWbrumrJojKZ1uwXrDviL6ySmVQD1UDQkX8E%2BqXHpTBNxLRa7yvNG8H7yV5VKTruueOeoZ1jJE4TmA4jT2iHhEfpk%2FWUIHfCJRyUICy%2BSnlQ4QGmisMn4Q8hnXSXIvf4PIAIhn2Y%2BAHU%2Bz1JUSLHRiUMoJfpYfoHzhwDOffOEKUxB9%2BMf8g%2BY%2Fe%2Fw8vNfI%2BEp%2BZNyNfyFZJdQX124f4ATh5eQterYNYkqNbUw7oBTfiXUwRXKlnrJynDMfcOiv2lrlbp6LCCujEKr9CrzPrzMPtXI3mWcbwmnnaEvpD6OTmUcHMTwyinPnLjVhwRSUm3IkThDDcLTWF76j5WbprcQLTYT4zloyg5IwYKKRrOIUpuhc6twBRnbcqPeGCxk%2Fig51zZ2%2FTncPirCT12duq%2B%2Bx%2BDK4GdVna4XXJ1qgfE4PccqvEFYm2ce96n3VakXmPitW9FaSHzYTIYA9EaFHOrFSFLB1xoQ20yM3RoTzdyuEUKOwdat5g68fVaKqmmCfGumHdUz5PmyNny2Yy0LqwNyE10dvd7nDfu97d2emSVHTyga%2B3vZkOQLrqm83NKlloVlYs3PwQws6q58DSO6TxVbTzLYKGybClgrEYLreJXJ930Jo5NmkwQtDfXZEyT%2BhIbFYZGgxrSbCrVbFtOTaImSvLhv6p060LR8sS4JnGHk9W0WFXDXK7RpqkRECIp%2BxobbxUjrJbVYy8mVzuaRofV6xz5%2Bc%2B0GQNGhtw5qjWEpCLXU73ZilfXGeNmllpgI4mXPw6TyZjhfChz71yg8wRQh76xcXInVt6qHpppvbJXl0GFGdgcG9W65Pm68y6UuaprrpMZERHK6EYeTMQ5N62JpzPr%2BAoUFKxHNfb2WitNXWWWGo70jWyB8vFb6hdzRop9ygeuSx7jGFoZE0KedmTKke3VoHFR5K6tz%2B9YL%2B08Q%2FQe6tjv8ziA%2Fs22b8zHLRRPX7XhrdxZpiSXW3MHo60u57FqaxugePkR4mOc8zI7%2FzRYeZxVlxuOOOJqjMLRnkXlgPe9HLd7OP%2BNrHm3X1nUOPhjOEHa%2BmkyOTMvaPr%2Fk12LMFxx5Mk6EMokf2xb6OuGU0FHkqCcqpqW2N2KEcSbRxpkTVnk3MyM2KHMDhnUwi6aqgJm64Ebo2NSeQkoN0qA8mv9rFlMXmw1jRZvdgrMPD%2BWbgIS6%2B%2FO%2BnNkY%2BEyc5nkyT1V7EOrS0%2F5HJtthcok%2BcEy9bOdplfw3XOJnxCj%2FuzPeyc7Sy9w7vYLHWWBoqNMtOdk4It7PVjkajjRJKVx8yuuaHijXSDS6PYpgrdsJ28ZJDEX9q0TevdehPsaruDbtK7ucbpAqbL9inNEbfLTNskbshn1XbCYgMEmUTzJFYPYqb08fLS7pntMPiy22r7ZHlslaHDl7sYjSfnzzrjK%2Fjz4%2Ff%2BHFYLE6C3FUApQ9D%2FwcrxikiKDQEAZBQBnGdwFid4mvd4AudphiVJPgxoLuLnOPWu4ceMr3%2BDP%2Bw%2Br38B&RelayState=s21d78f6780da128b12694232f7c038d0528d3b3d0&SigAlg=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2F04%2Fxmldsig-more%23rsa-sha256&Signature=vJiY1ewwdleN3H%2Bu%2F2vOXIK9DavmbYIhDYLNXRkuGM5oLsurxJUDFFj3C86lItYby3W71xEFXyQFuQWwhab1P2dSNmYfsxzq2xCzVS71%2Fsu%2B1rwFc5mDMs4yvgt8tOGF0wb3ngJp%2F3batEWEkrHzY5N0LIEbzQ7IaKoP9CwTjMj%2FVdqW9sT3xDQAmANsv4%2FURb1aLMqdMCC%2BUCFpWWL88FBfvg2oPWb36DUseymoxMvQ9rURjds5kFDnZ8eNeHnvuZ%2FEUhBFf1%2Fj8ygRhN8wf9vSo5B9cdqfNqT9cH8yieOh7glMPv4%2Btym4H940ZeKWyXzEYVyiOBzroEVGN4PbOA%3D%3D HTTP/1.1
Host: testportal.myatphub.ca
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:62.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Referer: https://uat.account.alberta.ca/account
Cookie: FedAuth=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; FedAuth1=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; ASP.NET_SessionId=ziliockmlr1jzsbmj2zcixul; __AntiXsrfToken=8ea4364534174ab09ee6942268f3d63e
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1

HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Content-Type: text/html
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
Date: Mon, 24 Sep 2018 16:45:28 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Length: 1245

Answer (score 0):

If you've updated from the old Kentor.AuthServices library to the new Sustainsys.Saml2, you need to set the `ModulePath` config to `AuthServices` to keep the old path. The new default is `Saml2`.